# "go to the city centre by subway" vs "travel to the city centre by subway"

Tags: phrase-usage

> I **go to the city centre by subway**.
>
> I **travel to the city centre by subway**.

Is it idiomatic to say "travel to somewhere" if there's no long distance between your home and destination point? May it be that "travel to the city centre" can be used only if you're outside the city?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of your sentences are natural. You can travel a long or short distance. The verb is not restricted in the way that you are asking about. You can travel to the centre of a city from the edge of the same city, or from another city. However, you would not use 'travel' about a very short distance, e.g. from one side of a road to the other.